# sum sub query sql

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to sum percent in sub query:

```
SELECT id, (
    SELECT COUNT( lead.id ) 
    FROM lead
    INNER JOIN cam c ON lead.cam = c.id
    WHERE c.id = c2.id
) AS leadtotal, (
    SELECT COUNT( landpagevisit.id ) 
    FROM landpagevisit
    WHERE c2.id = landpagevisit.cam
) AS visittotal, (
    SELECT COUNT( lead.id ) 
    FROM lead
    INNER JOIN cam c ON lead.cam = c.id
    WHERE c2.id = lead.cam
) / (
    SELECT COUNT( landpagevisit.id ) 
    FROM landpagevisit
    WHERE c2.id = landpagevisit.cam
) *100 AS conver, (
    SELECT SUM(
        (
            SELECT COUNT( lead.id ) 
            FROM lead
            INNER JOIN cam c ON lead.cam = c.id
            WHERE c.id = lead.cam 
        ) / (
            SELECT COUNT( landpagevisit.id ) 
            FROM landpagevisit
        )
    )
    FROM landpagevisit
    WHERE landpagevisit.cat = c2.cat
) AS totalconver
FROM cam c2
WHERE cat =1
```

I get this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|cat| camid |countvisitweek|countvisit|countlead|conver|totalconver|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|1  |25     |6             |6         |378      |63.000|62399      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|1  |23     |139           |139       |406      |2.9209|62399      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|1  |43     |34            |34        |51       |1.5000|62399      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|1  |61     |38            |38        |50       |1.3158|62399      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want that totalconver will be SUM of conver, now its 62399, its neet to be 68.737.
I need that this will sum conver, NOT to get conver with all the lead and the visit (NOT like this: 885/217 = 4.078341014).
do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calculating conver and totalconver differently.

conver:

```
  (SELECT COUNT( lead.id ) FROM lead INNER JOIN cam c ON lead.cam = c.id WHERE c2.id = lead.cam) 
    / 
  (SELECT COUNT( landpagevisit.id ) FROM landpagevisit WHERE c2.id = landpagevisit.cam) *100 AS conver,
```

totalconver:

```
(SELECT SUM( 
  (SELECT COUNT( lead.id ) FROM lead INNER JOIN cam c ON lead.cam = c.id WHERE c.id = lead.cam ) 
  / 
  (SELECT COUNT( landpagevisit.id ) FROM landpagevisit)) FROM landpagevisit WHERE landpagevisit.cat = c2.cat ) AS totalconver
```

If I compare the second count() between the two subqueries:

```
conver:
(SELECT COUNT( landpagevisit.id ) FROM landpagevisit WHERE c2.id = landpagevisit.cam)

totalconver:
(SELECT COUNT( landpagevisit.id ) FROM landpagevisit)
```

This seems to be too broad a net to be cast.  Try this instead:

```
(
    SELECT SUM
    ( 
      (SELECT COUNT( lead.id ) FROM lead INNER JOIN cam c ON lead.cam = c.id WHERE c.id = lead.cam ) 
        / 
      (SELECT COUNT( landpagevisit.id ) FROM landpagevisit WHERE c2.id = landpagevisit.cam)
    ) FROM landpagevisit WHERE landpagevisit.cat = c2.cat
  ) AS totalconver
```

Comment: HI, Thank you for your answer. I did it and this is give me error: 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row. do you know what to do?

Comment: What happens if you try to run the subqueries just by themselves?  So, what are the results for these two queries:

SELECT COUNT( lead.id ) FROM lead INNER JOIN cam c ON lead.cam = c.id WHERE c.id = lead.cam

SELECT COUNT( landpagevisit.id ) FROM landpagevisit WHERE c2.id = landpagevisit.cam

Answer (score 0):

> ## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
>
> this is what this wrote...
>   for this:

```
(
    SELECT SUM
    ( 
      (SELECT COUNT( lead.id ) FROM lead INNER JOIN cam c ON lead.cam = c.id WHERE c.id = lead.cam ) 
        / 
      (SELECT COUNT( landpagevisit.id ) FROM landpagevisit WHERE c2.id = landpagevisit.cam)
    ) FROM landpagevisit WHERE landpagevisit.cat = c2.cat
  ) AS totalconver
```